# How to maintain overlay layer in front even when baselayer is changed

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with 3 base layers and 2 overlay layers. When the user clicks to show the overlay layer it is properly displayed as the frontmost layer. However, when the user changes the base layer, while the overlay is still clicked, the base layer is brought to the front. I would like the overlay layers to always be displayed as the frontmost layer.

I've tried to change the zIndex of the overlay layers, I've also tried the following code:

```
var baselayers = {
    "Total Votes Cast": TotalVoteCountLayer,
    "Andrew Cuomo Votes": CuomoLayer,
    "Cynthia Nixon Votes": NixonLayer,
};

var overlays = {
            "NYS Assembly Districts": AssemblyOverlay,
            "NYC Council Districts": CouncilOverlay,
};

L.control.layers(baselayers, overlays).addTo(mymap);

mymap.on('baselayerchange', function(eventLayer) {
    if (eventLayer.name === 'NYS Assembly Districts'){
    overlays.bringToFront();
    }
    if (eventLayer.name === 'NYC Council Districts'){
    overlays.bringToFront();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following solution:

```
L.control.layers(baselayers, overlays).addTo(mymap);

mymap.on('baselayerchange', function() {
    if (mymap.hasLayer(AssemblyOverlay)) {
        AssemblyOverlay.bringToFront();
    }
    if (mymap.hasLayer(CouncilOverlay)) {
        CouncilOverlay.bringToFront();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

BringToFront is a Leaflet vector layer method. It will not work on your `overlays` dictionary of layers.

The correct general solution is indeed to use the `zIndex` option on your layers. If you need help on that, please show how you tried it so that we may be able to understand why it did not work.

Comment: thank you. Here's what I've tried with setting the zIndex.                                       function councilstyle(councilfeature) {
 return {
  fillColor: "purple",
  fillOpacity: .02,
]  color: '#2b2e5e',
  zIndex: 2000,
 };
}                                                                                                                                      var CouncilOverlay = L.geoJson(QueensCouncilDistricts, {
 style: councilstyle,
 onEachFeature: councilOnEachFeature,
})

Comment: `zIndex` is not part of the style object, but an option of the Leaflet GeoJSON factory, alongside `style` and `onEachFeature`. Note: you should _edit_ your question to add details, instead of posting them in comments.